# Joint distribution of $\left(\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3\right)$ converges to a 3D Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

I'm trying to teach my self the first 10 chapters of the book out of interest: "Leonid Koralov, Yakov G. Sinai - Theory of probability and random processes".

In chapter 8 (Weak Convergence of Measures), the last problem didn't really make sense to me, neither did it to my professor.

---

**Problem:** Let $\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots$ be independent random variables uniformly distributed in the ball
\begin{align*}
\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2+\ldots+\xi_n^2 \leq n
\end{align*}
Prove that the joint distribution of $\left(\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3\right)$ converges to a three dimensional Gaussian distribution.

---

Essentially we don't see why $\left(\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3\right)$ should converge to anything, since they're fixed. Are we missing anything? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure "independent" should be there? If you remove that word, the rest makes sense.

Comment: I think $\xi_i$ is supposed to be $\xi_{i,n}$. Without dependence on $n$ we can prove that $(\xi_i)$ does not even exist.

Comment: @Adam, Well, the book says independent. How do you then understand/solve the question if they’re not independent?

Comment: If they're not independent, I would assume it's saying the vector $(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n)$ is generated uniformly over the ball $\lVert \xi \rVert^2 \le n$. As $n \to \infty$, the first three coordinates $(\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3)$ converge to a multivariate Gaussian.